# Getting JSON objects from website using standard json and urllib2

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I wrote a code to extract JSON objects from the github website using json and requests:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json') #Replace with your website URL

with open("a.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in r.json or []:
        try:
            f.write(item['repository']['name'] + "\n") 
        except KeyError: 
            pass
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I want to do the same thing using urllib2 and standard json module. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply download the data with [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) and parse it with Python's [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
import json
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen('https://github.com/timeline.json')

with open("a.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in json.load(r) or []:
        try:
            f.write(item['repository']['name'] + "\n") 
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am getting this error while running the code:

  for item in r.json or []:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: Well, you have to parse the JSON yourself. Updated.